# Need some explanation on the VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i need some explanatory help on this code

```
EqptCode = .Range("A" & j)
StartPos = InStr(1, EqptCode, ">")
LastPos = InStr(2, EqptCode, "</")
CharNo = Len(EqptCode) - (Len(EqptCode) - LastPos + 1) - StartPos
EqptCode1 = Mid(EqptCode, StartPos + 1, CharNo)
```

anybody know what's the meaning of +1 in VBA language? is it something to do with rounding up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have numeric variables. Therefor you can subtract or deduct from those values.

Comment: *what's the meaning of +1 in VBA language?* `InStr` returns an integer value and it's stored on `StartPos`.  So when you do `StartPos + 1` you are just adding 1. Same for `LastPos `

Comment: And to complement JvdV and Foxfire And Burns And Burns, the integer value is used in Mid to get a section of the String EqptCode starting with the character next to ">" (value found with InStr) and up to the value calculated in CharNo - though the code is incomplete it looks like it is "extracting a code from a cell value preceded with special character ">" and "</". If more help is needed, you could include sample code, bur I suggest looking at Mid VBA Excel function specs (eg, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function).

Answer (score 0):

The +1/-1 is a common requirement .  It occurs when working with two different methods of expressing the position of the first item in a sequence i.e. whether counting starts at 1 or at 0.  When you mix the two systems you will always find the +1 or -1 appearing to ensure correct movement between the two systems.  In the case of VBA the position of a character in a string always starts from position 1, you can't have a character at position 0. However when you calculate the length of a string it is perfectly possible to have a value of 0.